# Shutdown Windows 10 truly for a dual booting system

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, shutdown, boot-partition

It seems that "Shut down" in Windows 10 actually means "Shut down and hibernate". This has caused my NTFS partitions cannot be automatically loaded on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) on my dual-booting laptop. There will be an error message basically saying

```
Unable to access “My Drive”

Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/D Center: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o  "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/D Center"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

After a "hard" shutdown by pressing *Shift* while clicking on "Shut down", Windows actually shuts down, and the NTFS partitions can then be automatically mounted by Linux in another bootup. This issue only occurs recently after my upgrade of the Windows OS and BIOS.

My question is the following: is there any way to make the "Shut down" on the menu as the truly/hard shutdown by default? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `Shutdown.exe -s -t 00` to shutdown your computer.  The current answer and only to this question, keep hibernated shutdown enabled, so I wouldn't recomend it.  *I will find the duplicate to this question after I have a better internet connection*

Comment: You edited your question to emphasize that *"This issue only occurs recently after my upgrade of the Windows OS,"* which makes sense.  But did you try our suggestions to alleviate the problem?

Comment: @Run5k, I have read your solution, but I haven't got a chance to restart my computer yet. I will definitely try in my next restart once my work is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried to disable the `Fast Startup` function?  Here is a good article that describes what it does, along with the potential drawbacks:

[The Pros and Cons of Windows 10’s “Fast Startup” Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)

That being said, `Fast Startup` is on by default and disabling it will probably alleviate your problem:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Select `Power Options`

   [image: Power Options]
3. Select `Additional power settings` on the right

   [image: Additional power settings]
4. Select `Choose what the power buttons do` on the upper-left

   [image: Choose what the power buttons do]
5. Select `Change settings that are currently unavailable`

   [image: Change settings that are currently unavailable]
6. Scroll to the bottom of the window and uncheck the box associated with `Turn on fast startup`

   [image: Turn on fast startup]
7. Click the button to `Save changes`
8. Reboot your system

([Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/))

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use `Shutdown.exe -s -t 00`?

Comment: @Ramhound , yes, absolutely... that is an excellent suggestion.  But then again, it is also easier to hold `Shift` while you select `Shutdown`.  Since the author emphasized *"My question is the following: is there any way to make the **Shut down** on the menu as the truly/hard shutdown by default?"*, I assume that he wants a set-it-and-forget-it solution that will accomplish his specific goal.