# how to disable fastboot on Acer for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, gpt, efi

How do I disable fastboot for this [Acer](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/model/NX.MLFAA.003)?

[image: no fastboot option]

I cannot see any option to disable fastboot on the UEFI "bios".

Comment: You disable **Fast Startup** within the Windows 10 `Power Options`.  You can find the proper method [in one of our previous questions](http://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002).

Comment: Rather than posting what is effectively the same question twice with minor amendments you should edit your previous question.