# Windows can't see my SSID unless I reboot router

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a D-Link off the shelf router, several devices with different OS / platforms are connected via Ethernet cable and WiFi.

My main laptop is a ThinkPad X230 with an Intel Centrino wireless adapter running Windows 10 and Linux Mint on separate partitions. I travel frequently and use many wireless APs, I am able to connect to them just fine using either Windows or Linux.

However, at home I can't see my SSID in the Windows menu, unless I go through these steps

- Switch router off
- Switch laptop wireless off (via hardware switch on side of laptop)
- Switch router on (wait for initialisation process)
- Switch laptop wireless on
- Now my SSID will be shown in the Windows Wifi menu and will connect successfully. It will work until I hibernate or switch the laptop off - after this I have to go through the cycle again.

I don't have this issue when I am booted into Linux, it always finds the WLAN when it is in range. 
There have been no changes or updates to the wireless adapter drivers and I have installed the latest ones from the Lenovo website. I don't have any unusual network settings, its just a consumer grade D-Link router and a standard Windows 10 installation.

How can I diagnose the fault?

Comment: Just to double-check, is your SSID configured within your router to be hidden by default?

Comment: @Run5k Definitely not, I have connected a new device today, and I just checked the settings at 192.168.1.1, also I have had people visit and connect their phones to the WiFi recently.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, you might try to [disable the Fast Startup function](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002) within Windows 10.  On my oldest laptop, it had problems connecting to the Wi-Fi until I made that change within the OS.  If that doesn't have any effect, you can easily turn it back on again.

Comment: @Run5k This is already disabled to allow dual booting using the GRUB bootloader.

Comment: Understood.  From my perspective, the first things that came to mind were the setting within Windows to *"Connect even if the network is not broadcasting"* and the *Fast Startup* function.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with a better suggestion.