# Grub Not Detecting Windows 10. (And Windows booting into hibernation mode?)

Tags: windows-10, installation, fedora

I'm relatively new to Linux (not to computers in general) and am trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Fedora 25. I installed Windows through a clean install, and restarted it a couple times, etc. to see that all was working. I then installed Fedora 25. Same drive, different partitions. I rebooted.

Unfortunately, Grub does not show me an option to boot into Windows 10- just Fedora 25 or Rescue mode for Fedora. Windows is now completely inaccessible. I googled around to try and see different fixes. Most of them involved at some step using nautilus to mount the partition. Unfortunately, upon trying that, I learned that Windows is in hibernation mode and I can't touch it. I have tried restarting, doing a number of things, and it would seem that Windows is booting into hibernation mode! Or something similar. I can't access it through nautilus. I can't get onto Windows10 to delete the hibernation file because of the bootloader.

I can't tell you how many times I've gone through this installation process, always with some problem or another. This seems to be the final one. Does anyone have any suggestions to allow me to boot onto windows?

Thank you kindly.

Sean

Comment: I am not a Linux guru, but I can probably help you in one aspect of this scenario:  when you have the opportunity to modify your Windows 10 configuration, you will find that it is beneficial is disable `Fast Startup` to help avoid certain Linux/Windows 10 dual-boot problems.  You can read about it within one of our previous questions:  [Shutdown Windows 10 truly for a dual booting system](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ntfsfix utility as described here:

http://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation-on-ubuntudebian-and-kali-linux/

The article for Ubuntu but will work on Fedora.  Install ntfsfix with

```
sudo dnf install ntfsfix
```