# Issue with LAN in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lan

I am using a Windows 10 x64 based Acer Laptop.

When I start work in morning, I connect the LAN to my LAP and for 1 month, there were no issues

But recently, when I connect the LAN, the Tray Icon shows **No Internet Access**,

When I troubleshoot it, the troubleshooter solve it and shows this was the error **Doesn't have a valid IP Config.**

Anyway, the issue is solved after troubleshooting.

#### Why this happens everyday, Since I am using the same Lan Connection and cable everyday.

#### How to fix it permanently(doesn't require a troubleshoot daily)

Comment: Try reinstalling the Network drivers.

Comment: You may be encountering an issue with the `Fast Startup` function.  [Disable Fast Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002) to see if that alleviates the problem.

Comment: Ah I have another question regarding that. @Run5k    https://superuser.com/questions/1191589/is-there-any-issue-if-laptop-didnt-shutdown-for-a-week

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read the article that I referenced within the previous answer.  I have an older laptop that simply wouldn't initiate the Wi-Fi connection unless I disabled the `Fast Startup` function, and that article helps explain why.

Comment: I am already on it. Will let you know

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I tried reinstalling it the driver but not working.

Comment: But did you try to disable the `Fast Startup` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try repairing Winsock & DNS Cache to clear the stored DNS cache in Windows. Sometimes when IP address settings become corrupt you will not be able to get internet connection.

Resetting IP settings will fix that problem additionally it also 
flushes and rebuilds the DNS and resets winsock entries TCP/IP stack.

You can try these commands in command prompt as admin

```
netsh winsock reset all
netsh int 6to4 reset all
netsh int ipv4 reset all
netsh int ipv6 reset all
netsh int httpstunnel reset all
netsh int isatap reset all
netsh int portproxy reset all
netsh int tcp reset all
netsh int teredo reset all
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?