# Windows reboots instead of shutting down after disabling fast startup

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, hibernate

I am running a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10 on a Lenovo t460p. In order to resolve hdd issues between the operating systems I disabled hibernate in Windows:

`powercfg /h off`

Since I did this change (confirmed as when I enable hibernate, all works as expected), Windows doesn't shutdown anymore, but always restarts when I hit the shutdown button. It is the second clean install I did and the issue is definitely caused by switching off hibernate. I can't find any restart problems that are related to fast startup settings and hope somebody can point in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the fact that shutdown will close all programs and then put windows to sleep. Your title suggests you have fast startup disabled, which would not use the hibernation anyway. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right, fast startup (which depends on hibernate as far as I know) is disabled; What I did is: I did a clean install, disabled fast startup and this odd behaviour occurs. After enabling it again, Windows shut down fine.

Comment: Maybe you can try this : http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-change-what-power-button-does-in-windows-7-3326053/

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you already perform the steps described within this previous question?  [Shutdown Windows 10 truly for a dual booting system](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002).  If so, you shouldn't really need to disable hibernate with the `powercfg` command.  You can simply [turn it off within advanced power options](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-enable-disable-hibernate-windows-10-a.html#option4)

Comment: I just tried it, but the problem remains; I ran `powercfg /h on` and just disabled fast startup in power settings.

Comment: That is rather strange.  Have you already tried to update your video card driver?

Comment: Maybe resetting all power configurations to default, then disabling fast startup can help.

Comment: Ok, I have a really weired update on this. I can successfully shutdown Windows when I turn it into flight mode before. So it might be related to my wifi/lte/Ethernet cards.