# Windows 10 keeps breaking file sharing

Tags: windows, windows-10, connection, file-sharing

Here's the deal - I've got three laptops (all of them on the same OS = Windows 10 Home 64-bit; all updates/fixes installed). To make it more clear, this is how the structure looks like:

- Laptop no 1 (let's call it server) - it has installed Firebird database and medical software which uses the database
- Laptop no 2 and 3 has the same medical software but they link/connect to the database from laptop #1

When I had previously Windows 8.1 everything worked smoothly - on laptop#1 I've shared necessary files and voila - worked like a charm. After upgrade to Windows 10 we've noticed that often the connection/file sharing between laptops is broken. This is frustrating because all computers work on the same Wi-Fi (they are pretty close to each other; no metal/brick walls etc), the same workgroup. But still the problem exists.

Any ideas for potential fixes or what i can change in the system settings to improve this situation?

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you tried? Have you made sure that file sharing is enabled?

Comment: @JustinKrejcha yeah, it's enabled. The issue is weird mainly because it sometimes works, sometimes not. I've disabled any screensavers, battery plan set for performance, wifi card eco mode is disabled.

Comment: When it doesn't work, I assume you just can't connect to it at all?

Comment: yes, indeed this is the case.

Comment: In production environments, avoid wireless like the plague for applications that require a persistent connection to a database. That's what remote desktop/remote app technologies are for.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - sure, i fully agree. Yet as said - at the moment i cannot use cable, need to focus on wifi. The only riddle is - why the hell it worked on W8 and NOT on W10?

Comment: @PawełSkaba That's a hard question to answer. Either Windows 10 is worse at wireless networking, or something has degraded in your environment. I find proposition #1 difficult to believe.

Comment: Your description of the problem is still rather vague, but I have found that my Windows 10 Wi-Fi connectivity within my `Workgroup` is noticeably more reliable when I [disable the Fast Startup function](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002) that is on by default.  And to add onto the good advice that Twisty posted, a work environment with "mission essential" machines probably shouldn't be configured with the *Home* version of Windows, either.