# Windows 10 - Reboot takes two minutes, shutdown and power-on takes 12 seconds to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, shutdown

I'm using Windows 10 v1709, i5 6600k and GTX 660. All drivers are updated and Windows is up-to-date.

So basically, clicking restart or when Windows crashes (talking about in-game crashes when it stutters for a second, then freezes for ~5 seconds and then just reboots, no BSOD or any message), takes longer than two minutes to reboot. My OS is on a new SSD. Shutting down the computer and then immediately powering it on takes ~12 seconds.

In those two minutes, it goes to the Windows logo in the same amount of time, and then just keeps spinning on the logo (powering off my peripherals in the meantime, a couple of times) and then finally arrives at the login screen.

Comment: As @Run5k states, Fast Startup depends on hybrid shutdown, equivalent to partially Hibernating. Your boot times are as expected.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have the opportunity to perform a test to see how long it takes after you temporarily [disable Fast Startup](https://superuser.com/a/1152002/650163)?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Disabling Fast Startup results in very similar boot times. I'm just baffled that it's possible for a normal Windows installation to boot on an SSD in more than 2 minutes on an SSD. Whatever the settings are.

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutdown-and-power-on scenario is relatively quick because [Fast Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) is enabled by default:

> **How Fast Startup Works**
>
> Fast Startup combines elements of a cold shutdown and the hibernate
>   feature. When you shut down your computer with Fast Startup enabled,
>   Windows closes all applications and logs off all users, just as in a
>   normal cold shutdown. At this point, Windows is in a state very
>   similar to when it’s freshly booted up: No users have logged in and
>   started programs, but the Windows kernel is loaded and the system
>   session is running. Windows then alerts device drivers that support it
>   to prepare for hibernation, saves the current system state to the
>   hibernation file, and turns off the computer.
>
> When you start the computer again, Windows does not have to reload the
>   kernel, drivers, and system state individually. Instead, it just
>   refreshes your RAM with the loaded image from the hibernation file and
>   delivers you to the login screen. This technique can shave
>   considerable time off your start up.

As a result, your shutdown-and-power-on procedure will typically be much faster than a reboot (which isn't affected by Fast Startup).

You can see the difference first-hand by temporarily disabling Fast Startup and then timing a few shutdown-and-power-on cycles for comparison.

Comment: So you are telling me that if fast startup didn't exist, Windows 10 would be booting in more than a minute even on high-end NVME drives?

Comment: I certainly don't claim to be a hardware expert, and there may actually be some additional problems occurring within your system. However, if you take some time to read through the article I referenced as well as some additional [Fast Startup tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html), you will find that this default function is probably responsible for the vast majority of the difference in your boot times.  As I said before, you can test this yourself by temporarily [disabling Fast Startup](https://superuser.com/a/1152002/650163).