# Selective allow of windows hibernate on certain partitions

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

We all know the common problem of Windows 8/10 doing a hybrid shutdown and preventing us to be able to access windows drives in ubuntu
[link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

I always assumed that since my windows uses the **C** partition. As long as the fast reboot is enabled it wont mount. But I was always confused why I couldn't access my **D:** partition.

Thanks to my new SSD I now have a 3rd partition **E:**. Now All 3 are locked in Ubuntu. -_-

The only work around is for me to boot into windows. And click restart and boot into Ubuntu using grub. (*The default shutdown in the start menu doesn't always work, because **hybrid shutdown***)

I want fastboot on, so I was wondering if I could selective allow windows to hybrid shutdown only on the **C:** drive. Since this is what it actually needs to boot.

The idea may be far-fetched since hybrid shutdown might involve saving the state of some of the other programs in the other partitions as well. But I just wanted to put this out there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I want fastboot on..."*  If you don't mind me asking, why?  We typically see a steady stream of posts within the Super User realm from people who encounter a wide variety of problems trying to dual-boot Windows 10 with Linux. However, some of those problems can easily be avoided if you [disable the Fast Startup function](https://superuser.com/a/1152002/650163) within Windows 10.

Comment: I do not care about my access to my C: drive. I store most of my files on D: and E. And if at all possible I would like access(read/write) to both of these drive in Ubuntu without removing fast startup. 
TL;DR I like my boot time. But want D: and E: access.

Comment: I understand that, but you didn't answer my question:  is there a compelling reason *why* you don't want to disable Fast Startup?  The [answer that I authored](https://superuser.com/a/1152002/650163) illustrates how easy it would be to avoid these problems, and the [Ask Ubuntu article](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904) that you referenced estimates that it would take another 40 seconds to boot into Windows after the modifcation.  That seems like a relatively small price to pay for a viable solution.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but the bottom line is that what you want isn't really possible. Ultimately, you will need to choose between "the lesser of two evils."  From my perspective, based upon the number of up-votes on both [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1152002/650163) as well as the [Ask Ubuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904), people who choose to disable Fast Startup within Windows 10 seem to feel that the extra ~40 seconds of OS boot time is a relatively minor inconvenience in order to have reliable access to their Windows partitions.

Comment: Alright. My entire question was if at all it was possible. I really didn't understand why windows was locking up partitions it had no business locking up. Just a curious mind. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: *"I really didn't understand why windows was locking up partitions it had no business locking up."*  Although there isn't anything inherently wrong with a dual-boot configuration, please keep in mind that when you reboot your computer into a Windows 10 environment, those D: and E: drives essentially belong to **that** operating system.  In other words, there are pros & cons involved with a dual-boot configuration.  Frankly, I typically recommend utilizing a free hypervisor like VirtualBox or Hyper-V to install the second OS.  It can help you avoid a lot of the quirks like this one!