# When I hibernate or turn off/on my Windows 10 PC, the NIC stops working

Tags: networking, windows-10, hardware-failure, network-adapter, win10-fast-startup

As the title states, every time I turn on my PC (or wake it up) I won't be able to connect to the Internet.

I have had this problem for quite some time and the only solution I have found so far is to disable and enable again the hardware component itself through the Control Panel.

The NIC in question is a Killer Networking E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (which is onboard, so I can't physically replace the part). Drivers are up-to-date, but the problem persists even with new updates.

Is there a way to fix this? Or, alternatively, a way to tell Windows to automatically disable/enable the NIC on startup?

Comment: I had the same problem when I originally upgraded my old laptop to Windows 10 a few years ago.  After doing some research online, I found that if I [disabled Fast Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system/1152002#1152002), the problem disappeared.

Comment: I'll look into this, but wouldn't that fix the problem only when turning the PC off rather than hibernating it?

Comment: Yes, that's potentially true, but probably still worth trying.

Comment: It seems to work both on power off and hibernating, but I'll have to test it for a few more times before being entirely sure. For the time being thanks a lot!

Comment: Your suggestion actually fixed my problem (sorry for the super late reply!). If you want to write it as an aswer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I originally upgraded my old laptop to Windows 10 a few years ago. After doing some research online, I found that if I disabled **Fast Startup**, the problem disappeared:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Select **Power Options**

   [image: Power Options]
3. Select **Additional power settings** on the right

   [image: Additional power settings]
4. Select **Choose what the power buttons do** on the upper-left

   [image: Choose what the power buttons do]
5. Select **Change settings that are currently unavailable**

   [image: Change settings that are currently unavailable]
6. Scroll to the bottom of the window and uncheck the box associated with **Turn on fast startup**

   [image: Turn on fast startup]
7. Click the button to **Save changes**
8. Reboot your system

---

Source:  [The Pros and Cons of Windows 10’s “Fast Startup” Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)