# Can't shutdown Windows 10 after a clean install

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot, windows-10-v1809

I had to reinstall Windows 10 a few months ago and am currently on v1809. For whatever reason, **I cannot shutdown my computer. Everytime I do, it restarts.**

I'm sporting an Intel Core i7 4770K on a Z87 motherboard.

Typing `shutdown /s` in the command line only restarts Windows.

I didn't make any changes to my UEFI settings and made sure to install the latest drivers for my chipset, graphics card, etc.

I tried disabling Fast Boot, but that didn't work either.

I also don't have anything like LAN boot enabled in the UEFI settings and disabling the Network Adapter's "Allow this device to wake the computer" didn't help either:
[image: Disabling Network Adapter auto-wake]

Disabling Automatic Restart on a blue screen didn't work which tells me it's not an error:
[image: Disabling Automatic Restart on Error]

Device Manager isn't showing any issues:

[image: Device Manager]

Looking at Event Viewer, there are three 10016 errors showing up after these system restarts. I'd read they're not important, but maybe they are:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}
 and APPID 
{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}
 to the user [MACHINE_NAME\USER_NAME] SID (S-1-5-21-4215124681-2051610619-607519943-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.


The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
Windows.SecurityCenter.WscBrokerManager
 and APPID 
Unavailable
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.


The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
Windows.SecurityCenter.SecurityAppBroker
 and APPID 
Unavailable
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

The only other one that looks suspect is this USB driver warning:

```
The driver \Driver\WUDFRd failed to load for the device USB\VID_17E9&PID_02FF\U70T08100303.
```

I don't have hibernation enabled so Fast Startup isn't even a thing:
[image: Choose what the power buttons do]

I also tried following the steps in this article but was unsuccessful:
https://www.pcworld.com/article/247392/windows/my-computer-reboots-when-i-tell-it-to-shut-down.html

I'm starting to wonder if it's a hardware issue. Possibly something wired up wrong on the motherboard. I am able to forcibly shut down by holding the power button for 4 seconds so to me, that rules out hardware issues.

I didn't clear the CMOS yet, but I did reset the UEFI settings to no avail.

Comment: Just to double-check, hopefully you realize that when you enter the command `shutdown /r /t 0`, you *are* telling the computer to restart.  The `/r` option does that.  If you want to actually shutdown, you want to use the `/s` option:  [shutdown | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown).  Beyond that, it also may help to [disable Fast Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1379404/when-i-hibernate-or-turn-off-on-my-windows-10-pc-the-nic-stops-working/1383731#1383731).

Comment: Typo on my part. Same issue using `/s`.

Comment: If that's the case, you should probably edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the process of correcting it when I responded.

Comment: The reasons for what your computer does during shutdown and restart are in the Windows event logs.

Comment: @Appleoddity Added more info including my recent event log errors.

Comment: Hi. Those are unrelated events. Please read through the events prior and up to the actual shutdown. The information you need is in there. It doesn’t necessarily have to be an error or a warning. I can’t tell you what the event IDs are off hand.

Comment: @Appleoddity The only other one that looks suspect is a USB driver warning. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Try shutdown from the start menu, hold the shift key when you click shutdown, does it shut down correctly now?

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: Check if Automatically restart is uncheck, under: Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced system settings->Startup and Recovery-> setting-> Uncheck Automatically restart.

Comment: @DaisyZhou Tried that checkbox already. I just updated my question to represent that one too.