# Why does turning my wifi network adapter on and off again speed up my internet by 10x?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

Every day when I resume my laptop from sleep mode, I notice the internet seems to be very sluggish.

However, just by toggling my wifi adapter on and off, the speed increases by 10x - I took the following screenshots of when I applied the "fix" today:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So why does this consistently happen and how to fix this once and for all?

I'm running Windows 10.0.17134 Pro on a Surface Pro 4.

Comment: Sounds to.me your adapter is.not fully wakibg up from sleep state. I speculate this is a driver or firmware issue.

Comment: From my perspective, this sounds like another variation of the following problem: [When I hibernate or turn off/on my Windows 10 PC, the NIC stops working](https://superuser.com/q/1379404/650163). Some devices are more suseptible to problems when they "awake" from sleep within a Windows 10 operating system, and WiFi adapters seem to be at the top of the list. Personally, I never put my laptop to sleep. It is either powered-on, or completely shut down with [Fast Startup disabled](https://superuser.com/a/1383731/650163). Give that a try, and your problems are likely to disappear.

Comment: First thing to try: install the latest drivers for your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 includes the USB selective suspend feature that lets you automatically put USB devices in a very low-power state when they're not actively in use. It's an important feature because it helps prolong battery life on your laptop or tablet, but it may also cause problems with certain peripherals connected to your PC.

If a USB device isn't working correctly, you can try to disable selective suspend on Windows 10. That may cause your computer to draw more power, but it may help to identify and fix the problem as well.

**How to disable USB selective suspend**

If you're having connectivity issues with USB peripherals on Windows 10, use these steps to disable the USB selective suspend feature.

Important: It's only recommended that you change this particular setting when you're experiencing problems with a USB device. Otherwise, you should leave the option enabled.

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Click on **Hardware and Sound**.
3. Click on **Power Options**.
4. Under "**Preferred plan,**" click the **Change plan settings** link for the plan you're currently using. (If you change the settings on the power plan that isn't active, this won't work.)

[image]

5. Click the **Change advanced power settings** link.

[image]

6. Expand **USB settings**.
7. Expand **USB selective suspend** setting.
8. Select **Disabled** from the drop-down menu.

[image]

9. Click **Apply**.
10. Click **OK**.

If you're changing the settings on a laptop or tablet, you'll see two options: On Battery and Plugged in, so make sure to change those settings accordingly.

Once you complete these steps, Windows 10 will no longer power off USB devices connected to your computer, which can fix any problem you may have as a result of this feature.

Side Note: also check the wireless settings there to see if you get that option too.

Comment: It's a Surface Pro 4. I doubt the network adapter is connected using USB, but the "Wireless Adapter Settings" might be the key here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [common problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/slow-wifi-after-instant-on-wake-up/7aa72739-6fca-44e4-9da9-365ad32f430a) with Surface laptops.

Here are some things you can try:

> 1. Go to the hardware manager -> network adapter -> Intel AX201 ->
>    Advanced -> MIMO power save mode -> Change "Auto SMPS" to "No SMPS".
>    While this resulted in the bug occurring less frequently, only
>    changing the setting to "Static SMPS" (-> disabling MIMO) eliminated
>    the problem entirely for me.
> 2. (Optional) Go to the Windows Settings App -> System -> Power & Sleep
>    -> When my PC is asleep and on battery power, disconnect from network -> Change "Never" to "Always"

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/dp96pb/psa_workaround_for_slow_wifi_after_waking_from/

It might be already fixed and all you you need to is to simply install the [latest drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49498).