# Very slow shutdown on Windows 11

Tags: windows, performance, windows-11, shutdown

I have been having a nasty problem on my Windows 11 for a few weeks. Where Windows will take over 7 minutes to shutdown. I have an NVMe drive for Windows, and it boots to a fully functional windows in less than a minute or so. But the shutdown is taking a very long time.

I have tried everything I could find. Including multiple suggestions, like:

- `HungAppTimeout` to `1000`
- `WaitToKillAppTimeout` to `2000`
- `AutoEndTasks` to `1`
- `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` to `0`
- turning off windows fast boot, including my motherboard fast boot option (MSI)
- enabling detailed shutdown messaging on Windows. And all it shows for 7 minutes is "shutting down" or "restarting".

I've even gone through this thread as well, [How can I identify the culprit of my slow Windows shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown), to enable a log and run windows performance analyzer, and I couldn't find the problem. As I can't read the log file properly. I've added a screenshot of the closest I can think of what the problem might be:

[image: Disk usage]

Comment: Try shutting down all open apps including saving all docs until only services are running. Then shut down.  Any change?   You may find an errant App.

Comment: I have shut them all down, from steam, onedrive, boom3d, msi, masterplus(coolermaster  rgb controller) , the browsers, icue, and everything i could find, or think of. And nothing. I did notice once, a week ago, when I turned off the computer as soon as it booted to windows that it shutdown fast. I thought it was something running, but I closed it all before and still no-go. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If you are domain joined and try to shutdown / reboot when the computer does not have access to the domain, try this: https://superuser.com/a/1824682/81203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have closed all apps and Windows 11 still takes a long time to shut down, it is time to consider repair options.

**(1) Test the hardware:**  Get the computer manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and look for hardware issues (memory and main disk especially).

**(2) Run DISM / SFC which is the simple initial repair:**

> (i) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (ii) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (iii) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (iv) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (v) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(3) If slow shut down remains, run a Windows 11 Repair Install:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.  The default Keep prompt is to Keep
> Everything.

**(4) If issues remain** and the hardware is OK, then there are more serious operating system errors and / or the Windows User Profile is damaged.

In either case, the most practical way forward is to completely back up and reinstall Windows 11.

I have 2 production Windows 11 Pro machines a 1 Windows 11 Pro insider machine and shut down is not a problem.

Comment: Is this option the one that creates a windows.old folder on C:\ with all the programs inside, including the user profiles? I tried with a new user profile, but the problem remained.  Thank you again for the reply. Do you understand or know how to properly read/interpret an .etl file? I did try the dism and sfc suggestion above. But haven't turned off the pc yet to test. But I  assume it won't work. Will update if it does.

Comment: A Repair Install with Keep Everything creates windows.old and puts you back where you were. Step 4 requires backing everything up prior to reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Ah, so the repair install leaves everything as is, and just repairs windows? Leaving the programs and profile files where they are?  Because I don't think I can afford the time or the problems if it all moves to windows.old, then having to move, manually, everything back to where it was...

Comment: Yes.  And if Repair Install fixes the slow shutdown - great.  If not then reinstall is the only option. Repair Install cannot fix a damaged User Profile either.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was hell dealing with this. I tried the repair-upgrade first, but the problem persisted. Decided to reinstall windows 11. And the problem was gone. After hours of installing the stuff I need, and testing the problem then returned. 
Turns out it was Boom3D driver. I disabled and uninstalled it, and the problem was gone.  After saturday testing to make sure, so far the problem is not here. Hope it continues this way.

Comment: You may now wish to acknowledge my answer as it has solved your issue.

Comment: Oh, found the icon to do that. Sorry for not doing it before. haha Thank you again for the help. Thought upvoting was the only action required.