# Weird disk behaviour

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, fdisk

Today I faced something completely strange. I run Windows 10 on a machine. On this machine I wanted to erase the internal HDD(not C drive) where just some data lays around. I booted into sparky linux live created a new gpt partition table + new partition of type Microsoft Basic Data in fdisk. Made a new ntfs filesystem using mkfs.ntfs. All commands completed successfully, but when I booted into Windows everything was still there??

Comment: Assuming you did not altered yet another drive by mistake, can it be the fast startup is enabled in Windows and the OS still remembers the old layout? If so, it can be a while until it reads data you actually altered under Linux and discovers the "corruption". Modern Linux [prevents you from writing to a filesystem affected by fast startup](https://superuser.com/q/1152001/432690), but I think you can freely wipe it like you did. Does the problem remain after you close Windows with `shutdown.exe -s -t 00` and reboot?

Comment: A full restart of windows actually helped