# Linux Mint over Windows 10, writing denied on HDD

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

A few weeks ago I tried Linux Mint on my 10 years old laptop and it worked way better than Windows. So I decied to keep it. But I wanted to keep all my old files, so I hadn't format my hard disk. I only format the particion where windows was, and replaced it with linux. But now I can only read those files. I don't have the permission to detele them or make new folders. What can I do?

Comment: Probably [this issue](https://superuser.com/q/1152001/432690) but the most common solution assumes there is Windows you want to use. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236145/108618).

Answer (score 0):

**Several different things may cause this**

Some reasons I can think of just now:

1. If the NTFS file system has errors, it will automatically be mounted as read-only to avoid corruption of data.

   - Check the file-system and fix errors.
2. Some NTFS drivers on Linux provide read-only file-system access.

   - Check the software center for different packages providing NTFS support.
3. Partition is mounted with *root* as both *owner* and *access group*.

   - Recursively change file ownership.

---

**Changigng ownership recursively**

Open a terminal in the respective directory, then issue the following command line

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 .
```