# No access to NTFS partitions from Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs

After a few updates on Windows and Kubuntu, on Kubuntu I no longer have write and modify access to NTFS drives, can only read NTFS partitions even as root.

Systen config: 128GB M.2-SSD drive, 1TB S-ATA-HDD drive.
Installed dualboot: Windows 10 Home, Kubuntu GNU/Linux

```
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/User/DataDrive (NTFS)
nvme0n1     259:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    60G  0 part /media/User/Windows-10-Home (NTFS)
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  58.7G  0 part /Kubuntu (XFS)
```

Comment: Does this help? [Shutdown Windows 10 truly for a dual booting system](https://superuser.com/q/1152001/432690)

Comment: Yes this helps. Shutdown Windows by holding shift-key. Fast startup option in Windows needs to be disabled. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As an administrator under Windows you can take ownership of the files and folders on your drive. If the linux driver supports that process, too, take ownership and grant yourself full access rights.